# Как отправляется электронные письма по протоколу https, если они должны отправляться по протоколу SMTP

Tags: https, smtp, протоколы

когда мы отправляем электронное письмо через браузер, оно отправляется на почтовый сервер через https?

объясните пожалуйста как это работает ? как я отправляю электронное почта через https ?

Comment: По https оно отправляется на сервера гугла/яндекса/мэйла/… а оттуда по протоколу smtp куда надо

Comment: большое спасибо...